# Do I have to leave off the skip call in my query

Tags: c#, linq

I have a big table in which I want to clear old records. The records have a field 'FilePath'. The 'clear' herein means mark the 'FilePath' as null. The question is because the table has millions of records, one time updating it is impossible. It blows up the memory. So my strategy is each time to fetch 2000 rows and update them then continue work on the next block.

My query:

```
int pageNumber = 0;
int pageSize = 2000;
bool hasHitEnd = false;

while (!hasHitEnd)
{
var size = pageNumber * pageSize;
var query = cdrContext.Mytable.Where(c => c.FacilityID == facilityID && c.FilePath != null && c.TimeStationOffHook < oldDate)
    .OrderBy(c => c.TimeStationOffHook)
    .Skip(size)
    .Take(pageSize)
    .Select(c => new { c.FilePath, c.FileName })
    .ToList();
      var q = cdrContext.Mytable.Where(c => c.FacilityID == facilityID && c.FilePath != null && c.TimeStationOffHook < oldDate)
         .OrderBy(c => c.TimeStationOffHook)
         .Skip(size)
         .Take(pageSize)
         .ToList();
foreach (var y in q)
{
   y.FilePath = null;
}
cdrContext.SaveChanges();
if (query.Count() < pageSize)
{
    hasHitEnd = true;
}
pageNumber++;
```

I am not confident the code. Because after updating the data, the FilePath is null. Then in the next run, it may not point to the right block as I skip one block.

Do I need to remove skip part?

Comment: This feels more like a utility function than a client-side function, would be best served as a stored procedure + scheduled job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to skip records, because after update next page will become first page (updated items will not match you query filter on next call).

```
// define query, but don't execute it
var query = cdrContext.Mytable.Where(c => c.FacilityID == facilityID && 
                                          c.FilePath != null && 
                                          c.TimeStationOffHook < oldDate)
                              .OrderBy(c => c.TimeStationOffHook)
                              .Take(pageSize);

List<Foo> itemsToUpdate = query.ToList(); // get first N items

while(itemsToUpdate.Any()) // all items updated
{
    // update items
    cdrContext.SaveChanges();
    itemsToUpdate = query.ToList(); // get first N items
}
```

Comment: You are right, there are two queries here. One is "query", the second one is "q", do you mean ignore skip in both? To judge where reach the end, use query.Count()<pageSize or q.Count()<pageSize?

Comment: @Love I added sample of code which shows how you can get first N items matching your criteria in a loop

Answer (score 1):

No need to skip records, subsequent page will be your first page. Also you dont need to query the db twice I see you use query and q which is not necessary. Just use q it will help a lot in perfomance. You can remove following code

```
 if (query.Count() < pageSize)
 {
     hasHitEnd = true;
 }
```

Replace that with count of records in q if q.Count() == 0 then you can break the loop or set hasHitEnd = true;